# LINQ query does not work without .ToList()

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Consider following LINQ-to-NHibernate queries:

```
var q1 = from se in query.ToList<SomeEntity>()
  where
  prop1 == "abc"
  select se;

var q2 = from se in q1
  where 
  m1(se.prop2) == "def"
  select  se;
```

`q2` will not work with error: "The method m1 is not implemented". But when replace `q2` with following query, everything goes ok:

```
var q2 = from se in q1.ToList<SomeEntity>()
  where 
  m1(se.prop2) == "def"
  select  se;
```

Why this happens? How can I get first query to work too? Is this something that happens for LINQ-to-NHibernate only or happens in all LINQ queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no way for the LINQ provider to translate the method m1 to a compatible SQL statement.

By calling `ToList<SomeEntity>()`, you are reading the entire thing into memory and then using LINQ to Objects to filter (and since the query doesn't get translated to SQL in that case, there is no problem running the query).

Unfortunately there is no easy way for you to get the first query to work. If you really need to use `m1` to filter results, you'll have to read things into memory first.

This is not just a LINQ to nHibernate limitation either. This will happen in any situation where a LINQ provider uses Expression Trees to convert your code into another language (in this case it is trying to convert your C# code into SQL statements which is the same thing that LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework do).

Comment: This is correct. However, NHibernate 3 **does** allow you to extend the LINQ provider to support any method call (of course, you must know how to create an HQL tree from it). See http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: amazing feature in NHibernate 3, many thanks for informing.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the method `m1` does not have a translation to SQL (at least, the NHibernate LINQ provider can't figure out how to). When you don't have the `ToList`, NHibernate is trying to figure out how to convert `m1` to SQL. When you do the `ToList`, NHibernate isn't playing a role anymore and its LINQ-to-Objects that can handle the query. This is specific to ORMs that enable LINQ; LINQ-to-SQL and EF will suffer similar fates.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your original q2 query is being translated into an expression tree and then when NHibernate tries to parse it, it finds that the method is not a part of its implementation.  Converting the query to a collection first with ToList() uses the LINQ functionality of the List which can support the m1 method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know NHibernate, but would this work ?

```
var q2 = q1.where (x => m1(x.prop2) == "def");
```